# How to get all the properties from a DirectoryEntry object

Tags: .net, active-directory, ldap

I try to write a procedure which fetches all the properties in an available `DirectoryEntry`

```
// create LDAP connection object  

DirectoryEntry myLdapConnection = createDirectoryEntry();  

// create search object which operates on LDAP connection object  
// and set search object to only find the user specified  

DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(myLdapConnection);  
search.Filter = "(cn=" + username + ")";  

// create results objects from search object  

SearchResult result = search.FindOne();  

if (result != null)  
{  
    // user exists, cycle through LDAP fields (cn, telephonenumber etc.)  

    ResultPropertyCollection fields = result.Properties;  

    foreach (String ldapField in fields.PropertyNames)  
    {  
         // cycle through objects in each field e.g. group membership  
         // (for many fields there will only be one object such as name)  

         foreach (Object myCollection in fields[ldapField])   
             Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0,-20} : {1}",   
                    ldapField, myCollection.ToString()));  
    }  
 }  

 else  
 {  
      // user does not exist  
      Console.WriteLine("User not found!");  
 }
```

When I Try to execute this procedure under one user, it returns me a list of properties but when I try to execute this procedure under a different user it returns me a different number of properties.

What kind of authorization do I need in order to get ***all*** of the properties?

Thanks in advance

Kobi

Answer (score 0):

By default all successfully logged on AD accounts (Authenticated Users) have read access to Active Directory (see https://blog.varonis.com/the-difference-between-everyone-and-authenticated-users/). However in some cases behavior may be changed by admin. To check, to which AD object attributes user has access, open ADUC snap in on any DC, open the desired AD object properties, go to Security tab. There you can see common security info for all users\groups. If you click Advanced button on the tab, then go to Effective Access tab, you can verify effective access permissions which desired security principal has on the object.

The simplest way is to connect to DC using account that belongs to Domain Admins\Enterprise Admins group. However I'd recommend to avoid this because of security reasons and configure permissions properly

Answer (score 0):

using LDAP:

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://KLM.ENS");

using (DirectorySearcher adSearch = new DirectorySearcher(entry))
{
    adSearch.Filter = "(sAMAccountName=userName)";
    SearchResult adSearchResult = adSearch.FindOne();
    foreach(var propertyName in adSearchResult.Properties.PropertyNames)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{propertyName} : {adSearchResult.Properties[propertyName.ToString()][0]}");                        
    }
}
```

using WinNT:

```
string Domain_Slash_Machine = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
Domain_Slash_Machine = Domain_Slash_Machine.Replace(@"\", @"/");
string queryString = @"WinNT://" + Domain_Slash_Machine;

DirectoryEntry obDirEntry = new DirectoryEntry(queryString);
System.DirectoryServices.PropertyCollection propColl =
obDirEntry.Properties;
foreach (var propertyName in obDirEntry.Properties.PropertyNames)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{propertyName} : {propColl[propertyName.ToString()].Value}");                    
}
```